# carry choice from one file to the next

Tags: python, file, tkinter

Im trying to make the choice of a button in a program,
carry on to the next program, using Tkinter (python 2.7 in windows).
I've been googleing away without luck. It is possible that I am
lacking the right lingo og buzzword.
Anyways, I hope that the question is clear. Thank you.

Let me try and demonstrate by the following:
...so we have two files: PROGRAM_1.py and PROGRAM_2.py they are to be in seperate files.

PROGRAM_1.py

```
from Tkinter import  *
import os
import Tkinter as tk

start_color = ["blue", "red"]
root = Tk()
root.title("please choose a starting color")
# Set background #
root.configure(background="green")
root.geometry("600x150")
# Buttons #
topFrame = Frame(root)
topFrame.pack()
bottomFrame = Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack(side=LEFT)

start_color[0] = Button(topFrame, text="Choose Blue", fg="black",     bg="white", font='bold')
start_color[1] = Button(topFrame, text="Choose Red", fg="black", bg="white",     font='bold')

start_color[0].pack(side=LEFT)
start_color[1].pack(side=LEFT)

def blue(event):
    print "u chose the blue"
    os.system("PROGRAM_2.py")
    # then exit and startup PROGRAM_2".py
start_color[0].bind("<Button-1>", blue)

def red(event):
    print "u chose the red"
    os.system("PROGRAM_2.py")
    # then exit and startup PROGRAM_2".py
start_color[1].bind("<Button-1>", red)

root.mainloop()
```

PROGRAM_2.py

```
from Tkinter import  *
import os
import Tkinter as tk

start_color = ["blue", "red"]

root = Tk()

print "your color is"
print start_color["......."]  # <--- And then the choice from PROGRAM_1.py

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the choice to `PROGRAM_2.PY` as a command line argument. You can access the command line arguments in `PROGRAM_2.PY` using the `sys.argv` list. So, in `PROGRAM2.PY` import `sys` and replace the line `start_color = ["blue", "red"]` with:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv > 1):
    start_color = sys.argv[1]
.
.
.
print "your color is", start_color
```

And in `PROGRAM_1.PY`:

```
def blue(event):
    print "u chose the blue"
    os.system("python PROGRAM_2.py blue")
    # then exit and startup PROGRAM_2".py

def red(event):
    print "u chose the red"
    os.system("python PROGRAM_2.py red")
    # then exit and startup PROGRAM_2".py
```

It's worth pointing out that `os.system()` does not exit the current process; it runs the given command as a new process and waits for it to terminate.

Comment: I am not able to make this work. Let me show you what I did. First of all you are removing the buttons in PROGRAM_1.py - so I added them again

Comment: No, I'm not removing the buttons - just replace the calls to `os.system()` to pass a command line argument.

Comment: So they both appear to work individually. But not together, meaning that when I click the button nothing happens. Recall that clicking the button in PROGRAM_1.py should open PROGRAM_2.py and write the print statement "your color:" and then the result of the button pressed.

Comment: Depending on your OS, you need to supply the correct path to `PROGRAM_2.py`, and that program needs to be executable, _and_ have the correct `#!` incantation at the top. If the files are in the same directory you should be able to use `os.system('python PROGRAM_2.py')` - assuming that the Python executable is on your path. I've updated the answer with this as it will be more likely to work.

Answer (score -1):

```
from Tkinter import  *
import os
import Tkinter as tk
import sys

root = Tk()


if (len(sys.argv) > 1):
    start_color = sys.argv[1]

print "your color is", start_color

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just a small syntax correction in line with:  if (len(sys.argv) > 1):